# Why these arrow buttons are not positioning to left and right

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I want these two left and right arrow buttons to be positioned left and right depending upon the props passed.

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import ArrowBackIosSharpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBackIosSharp';
import ArrowForwardIosSharpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowForwardIosSharp';

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff6a9;
`;

const Arrow = styled.div`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff7f7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  left: ${(props) => props.direction === "left" && "10px"};
  right: ${(props) => props.direction === "right" && "10px"};

  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2;
`;

const Slider = () => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Arrow>
                <ArrowBackIosSharpIcon direction="left" />
            </Arrow>
            <Arrow>
                <ArrowForwardIosSharpIcon direction="right" />
            </Arrow>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Slider;
```

I am passing left and right as props to styled components but this is not working.

Comment: If both `left` and `right` are present, `left` will be taken into account and `right` ignored

Comment: @Konrad Then, Do I have to create two different Styled Components for Left and Right Arrow

Comment: First of all, if the function passed doesn't evaluate to true, you'll get `false` instead of `0px` or such. Besides that, as per the other comments when both left and right are present left has precedence, so you should try something like this instead: `${props => props.direction}: 10px;`. Also, you're not even using your styled component. You're using the built-in unstyled component instead.

Comment: `left` needs to be `auto` for `right` to take priority. Even if `right` is defined first

Comment: You're not supplying the `direction` prop to your styled component, only to the `~Icon` components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide props to the Arrow component not the left arrow and right arrow.

```
        <Arrow direction="left">
            <ArrowBackIosSharpIcon  />
        </Arrow>
        <Arrow direction="right">
            <ArrowForwardIosSharpIcon  />
        </Arrow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are checking the props on the 'Arrow' component, you will need to pass the props to it and not the 'ArrowBackIosSharpIcon' component. Like this:

```
<Arrow direction="left">
    <ArrowBackIosSharpIcon />
</Arrow>
<Arrow direction="right">
    <ArrowForwardIosSharpIcon />
</Arrow>
```

Additionally, you can render the style property itself conditionally by replacing:

```
left: ${(props) => props.direction === "left" && "10px"};
right: ${(props) => props.direction === "right" && "10px"};
```

with this:

```
${(props) => props.direction === "left" && "left: 10px"};
${(props) => props.direction === "right" && "right: 10px"};
```